# How do you convert an integer into its CONDENSED binary equivalent e.g. BINARY(3) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, binary, type-conversion, data-conversion

I'm performing hash operations, and I need to append raw bytes consistently, accurately, efficiently, etc.
I can't screw around with ASCII-encoded strings of numbers, I just need to get raw bytes.

MySQL's conversion functions are very confusing, and don't produce results that would seem obvious to a SQL-Server guy like me.

For example, `BINARY 123456` produces an ASCII-encoded string with 6 characters, rather than the seemingly obvious `BINARY ( 3 )` string `00000001 11100010 01000000` aka `0x01E240`

So far, the only way I can get the correct conversion, is by assigning a hex literal - which is obviously impractical at runtime.

```
SET @int_value = 123456 ;   -- Decimal value

SET @hex_value = 0x01E240 ; -- The same value, in hexadecimal,
                            -- 6 hex digits = 3 bytes

SELECT LENGTH ( BINARY @int_value ) , LENGTH ( BINARY @hex_value ) , LENGTH ( BINARY HEX ( @int_value ) ) ;
```

[image]

So in this example, how can I convert an integer value (e.g. `DECLARE`'d integer variable or integer column) `123456` into a string of 3 bytes?

**EDIT:**
As requested in the comments, SQL-Server produces the desired results by default:

[image]

This is the behavior I need to emulate in MySQL.

Comment: What specific output would you like for the result?  A number is a value which can be expressed in many ways.  Possibly the client side needs to do some formatting, depending on your requirements.  If you know of a SQL Server mechanism, show that so we can figure out what you might mean.

Comment: @wallyk There's a giant orange box around the desired result. I also typed the desired result above that: *3-byte binary string `00000001 11100010 01000000`* SQL-Server behaves this way by default: `SELECT CONVERT ( BINARY ( 3 ) , 123456 )` produces a 3-byte binary string `0x01E240`

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand the confusion around this question. This is a data-type conversion problem. The display/formating is irrelevant. So when I say ***binary string of three bytes*** I'm referring to a three-byte storage value, not a string of 1's and 0's. This seems so natural to me, and I didn't expect to have to explain it. Perhaps the MySQL community is notably different from the SQL-Server community in this regard. **TL;DR** This is a database, not a spreadsheet or word-processor. The *storage/manipulation* of the data is what matters, not the formatting/display.

Comment: Hmm:  `123456` *is* a three byte sequence.  The storage of it is generalized by databases.  Please explain *The display/formatting is irrelevant* seems to contradict the title of the question *How to convert an integer into its condensed binary equivalent*.  An integer held in a database is (roughly) condensed as it can be.  If you want it displayed in hexadecimal, then `SELECT hex(123456)` is one way.

Comment: @wallyk `123456` is stored as a 4-byte integer, generally speaking. `An integer held in a database is (roughly) condensed` "Roughly" is the problem there. `If you want it displayed in hexadecimal...` I don't care how it's displayed. I'm building hash-focused algorithms for security applications, and I need to manipulate the bytes in various ways. I need flexibility and precision, not generalization or abstraction. As you can see from the MySQL screenshot in my question, `BINARY [X]` produces strings of ASCII characters, converting the number into text, except with hex literals for some reason.

Comment: @wallyk `seems to contradict the title of the question` Yeah, the title isn't great ... I just updated the title to include the specific data type I'm trying to convert to `BINARY(3)`, but honestly I'm not sure how much of an improvement that is.

Comment: @giffguy is the input always going to be an unsigned integer (0 ... 4294967295) or signed (-2147483648 ... 2147483647)? Or something else?

Comment: @SalmanA In reality, I'll also need to adapt for signed/unsigned bigints ... but adapting whatever solution to 64 bits is easy enough. Likewise with mediumints, smallints, and tinyints. And lastly, if the input is already a binary string, then there's no work to do, so I think that covers all sizes of numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [HEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) to generate a string with a hexadecimal representation of your integer. Then [UNHEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex) will convert that string to a binary value:

```
SET @int_value = 123456;   -- Decimal value

SET @bin_value = UNHEX(HEX(@int_value));

SELECT @int_value, HEX(@bin_value), LENGTH(@bin_value);
```

results in

```
@int_value | HEX(@bin_value) | LENGTH(@bin_value)
-----------|-----------------|-------------------
    123456 |          01E240 |                  3
```

See [demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a6d8c3984f7ee397a9cd5053f2668a1a)

Comment: Oh interesting! I wonder if MySQL actually optimizes this in the background, and skips the string conversion. A very neat solution, either way!